# is there a book (or a book's series) where all of mathematics (or the great part) has been developed from ZFC or any other set theory?

Tags: logic, set-theory, foundations

I am studying Mathematics and I have interest in the foundations of Mathematics. I have studied mathematical logic and set theory, and many time I have found in the study that you can derive all of mathematics from set theory (ZFC). Well, is there a book (o a book's series) where all of mathematics (or the great part) has been developed from ZFC or any other set theory?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127170/discussion-on-question-by-marco-medina-is-there-a-book-or-a-books-series-wher).